# Is Kubernetes Admission Controller webhook execution race-safe?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a metric counter that records during the execution of multiple webhooks.
Do we need to implement locking when incrementing the metric counter to prevent race conditions?

Apart from this, does the admission controller support handling multiple admission requests simultaneously? For example, if there are 2 admission requests, will the admission controller execute one after another, or simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is that the requests are an API call behind the scenes and are executed **simultaneously**.

#### A bit longer answer will be:

- The requests are API calls.
- Behind the scenes, there are "hooks" that intercept the requests and execute them.
- The above request can generate latency in some cases when there is a problem and they are not processes, then can even throw a timeout.
- The requests can be divided into "buckets" per namespace.
- You can limit the number of requests per namespace
- You can limit by a specific user